# what support for jetpack compose is in android studio 4.2 beta 1

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

In previous android studio releases, once the version became 'beta' compose was removed. 4.2 is the first version to reach beta since compose left 'developer preview status', so it is time for compose to reach beta?
From what i can see, compose still has many clues it should be supported in the new 4.2 beta 1 (like now compose being a 'bundled plugin' under plugins), but there is no option to create a new compose project, unless some setting i have is hiding that option.

Anyone know what is happening with compose in studio 4.2?

Any clues about what triggers compose reaching at least beta releases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've opened my project which is compatible with AS 4.2 Canary 16 with AS 4.2 Beta 1 and I got this:

> Jetpack Compose is a preview feature, and support for Compose is included only in Canary versions of Android Studio. To use Compose in your app project, download and install the latest Canary version of the IDE.

[image]

If your project doesn't build successfully to see that dialogue, be sure you have this version for gradle build plugin in your classpath:
`com.android.tools.build:7.0.0-alpha02`

And [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-studio-42-beta-1-available.html), it doesn't mention to Compose.
So, the only solution is using Canary versions, which it has been mentioned supports Compose.

Comment: Thanks.  I was not sure if that was happening this time, since this the first beta since compose escaped developer preview. As you say, in the notes it does not mention jetpack compose, yet under 'settings/plugins' compose is listed as 'bundled plugin', and in other settings the editor even has a compose option within color schemes - with sample compose code shown.  which is all strange for a version that does not support compose

Comment: Also interesting since compose is officially no longer a 'preview feature'